# Customizing Gnome Shell in 11.10

Tags: unity, gnome, configuration, gui

Since Unity on my old MBP is not that snappy, I really want to change my GUI to Gnome Shell.
However, I've really been struggeling with the customization of Gnome Shell. Can you help me with the following:

1. Is is possible to have the dock on the screen all the time?
2. Can I enable 'hot corners' for features like 'scaling' in compiz?
3. Is there a ccsm-like GUI configuration tool?
4. Can I enable wobbly windows in Gnome Shell?
5. How do I change the shortcut for the WIN-KEY to start this 'Gnome-Mission-Control' (by that I mean this thing u see when going to the top left corner).

Thank you.

Comment: Your question may be better broken up into separate posts. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Yes, by using an extension called "Dock" which is available in the WebUpd8 GNOME3 PPA. Install it using the commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-dock
```

Then you must restart GNOME Shell or log out and log back in and activate it using GNOME Tweak Tool (see answer 3).

To customize the dock extension, install dconf-tools (sudo apt-get install dconf-tools), then launch "dconf-editor", navigate to org > gnome > shell > extensions > dock and here you can specify the dock position (left or right), enable or disable autohide, specify the hide effect or set the hide duration.

From [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/official-gnome-shell-extensions.html).

2) Not that I know of.

3) What exactly do you want it for? I guess the closest thing to CCSM but for GNOME Shell is GNOME Tweak Tool. Install it using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

GNOME Tweak Tool shows up as "Advanced settings" in the menu.

4) No.

5) The SUPER / WIN key already triggers the activities overview (this also works with Alt + F1). Do you want to use a different key? You can set a custom key by opening System Settings and under Keyboard > Shortcuts > System change the keyboard shortcut for "Show the activities overview" from Alt + F1 to whatever you want (but make sure that keyboard shortcut is not already in use).

Answer (score 1):

4) Wobbly windows: https://github.com/magcius/gnome-shell-wobbly-windows

I need to figure out how to enable it though.